# Don't see the masterpage option in the site settings

Tags: 2013, master-page

I have a sharepoint 2013 portal. When I go to the site settings I normaly see the option "Masterpage". I dont see it at this moment. What can I do to change the masterpage?

Answer (score 1):

You will only see the option "Master Page" if the site is a Publishing site (having publishing features enabled)

The Url to the master page settings is `/_layouts/15/ChangeSiteMasterPage.aspx` which will throw an error on for example a Team Site

Comment: Really?  What a shame I used that a lot in 2010 :(

Comment: In my environment this is the case at least :/ Only for publishing sites can I access the page successfully through the link above

Answer (score 0):

enable publishing feature from site settings. Goto site settings >> Site Collection feature and activate **SharePoint Server Enterprise Site Collection features** this feature.